Can not find default export after linking local module
I am trying to fix an issue with React-Apex-Charts which is an open source NPM library. However after linking the local version of the module to my project and importing it like this: import ReactApexChart from "react-apexcharts I get the error that:The requested module '/@fs/Z:/repos/react-apexcharts/dist/react-apexcharts.min.js' does not provide an export named 'default'. This is wierd because when I go to the source code of the file by going to the type definition I can clearly see that in the last line we have: export default class ReactApexChart extends React.Component<Props> {}. I have also tried to understand if it was an issue related to the .min file as the error suggests. The export part looks like this which I do not understand:
((exports.default = Charts).propTypes = {
  type: _propTypes2.default.string.isRequired,
  width: _propTypes2.default.oneOfType([
    _propTypes2.default.string,
    _propTypes2.default.number,
  ]),
  height: _propTypes2.default.oneOfType([
    _propTypes2.default.string,
    _propTypes2.default.number,
  ]),
  series: _propTypes2.default.array.isRequired,
  options: _propTypes2.default.object.isRequired,
}),
  (Charts.defaultProps = { type: "line", width: "100%", height: "auto" });

I also tried running npm run build to generate new min files.
When I run npm ls it gives out:
├── react-apexcharts@1.4.1 extraneous -> .\..\react-apexcharts
which probably confirms that the local link is successful.
When I do this:
import * as ReactApexChart from "react-apexcharts"
console.log(Object.keys(ReactApexChart))

I get this error: uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined at react-apexcharts.min.js:1:36
After these steps I do not have any idea how to continue. The default export normally works when the library is installed trough NPM.
